# How many times did a person enter a journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, journeybuilder

I need to figure out how many times a person entered a journey in Marketing cloud.
I was able to query how many emails did a person get in a journey by querying the _Journeyactivity Data View, but I couldn't find a way to count the entry actions.

The only thing I can think about is to create a new DE with the Subscriber key and entry date as being Primary Keys, add an update contact activity as a very first step in the Journey, and add the person to that DE and Count how many times the person is in that DE.

The reason for this is that I only want someone to go into the journey 3 times if they don't meet the goal criteria.

Thanks,
Andrei

Answer (score 0):

How I resolved this, is that I created a duplicate of the Entry DE, and used a query (update) to pull in the people from the actual Entry DE (since that was an overwrite). In the new DE I have created a DateEntered Date field, and set that as a primary key as well. So people can get in that DE multiple times. Then i created a query that counts how many times a Subscriber key is in the DE. And save that info in a 3rd DE which basically has the subscriber key and the nr of times the person entered.
Then I could use that 3rd DE to filter at the entry points so people who were already in there 3 times should not go in for the 4th time.

Hope this helps someone.